# URGENT - TEX file opens without anything written

Tags: errors

Friends,

I need an urgent help from friends.

I use TexStudio and today I worked all day in a chapter of my work.

I stopped the night now and when I came back I put it to save again before exporting to the Cloud and to my External HD, but suddenly the computer hung up

I turned the computer on, it came back but my chapter that I wrote is size 31 kb   but appears blank, I do not know what to do, any suggestions so that I do not lose my job?

I thank you

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64349/discussion-on-question-by-cleber-iack-urgent-tex-file-opens-without-anything-w).